# Added credit card not showing up

Tags: civicontribute, drupal, payment

I recently discovered that our payment processor does in fact accept a credit cared type that wasn't enabled before. I went to Administer > CiviContribute > Accepted Credit Cards and enabled the card (Discover). Then I cleared caches and CiviCRM caches but the credit card button isn't showing up. We are using Authorize.net.

In the screenshot below, you can see that it still only lists Visa, MasterCard, and American Express.

[image]

CiviCRM 5.0.0

Update: Strangely, on my test site, it works just fine on 5.1.2 so when I upgrade production tonight, the issue might just go away.

Comment: Hi Christia! You can tell us what processor you're using as well, since most civicrm payment processors are extensions.

Comment: Looks like you meant to include a screenshot ...

Comment: We are using Authorize.net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the issue was unrelated to the version of CRM I was running. The payment processor settings also needed to be edited to include Discover, after adding it to the list of accepted credit cards; Administer > CiviContribute > Payment Processors. After I cleared everything in the `sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c` directory, I was able to see the settings to turn it on. Oop!

[image]